# How can I use an Apex Trigger to start an Autolaunched Flow and pass in a collection of new records?

Tags: visual-workflow, after-trigger, collection-variable

I have an object that receives frequent imports. We tried a record-triggered flow to handle after-save processing of related records, but we're hitting limits with import files >100 records. Record-triggered flow interviews only run on one record, but autolaunched flows can work on collections.

What I want to do is use an Apex trigger to launch a Flow and pass in the collection of new records. This way the Flow can process the new records in loops and perform the DML at the end on the whole batch instead of multiple DML calls per new imported record.

Here is my current code:

```java
trigger InboundReferralTrigger on Inquiry__c (after insert) {

    List<Inquiry__c> inputInboundReferrals = trigger.new;
    
    Flow.Interview.Inbound_Referral_Apex_Triggered_Flow myFlow = new Flow.Interview.Inbound_Referral_Apex_Triggered_Flow(inputInboundReferrals);
    myFlow.start();         
}
```

And here is the error message I receive when I try to deploy:

> Constructor not defined:
> [Flow.Interview.Inbound_Referral_Apex_Triggered_Flow].(List<Inquiry__c>)
> (5:66)

I'm using [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/flow_interview_class.htm#flow_interview_class) as the starting point for my code:

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the documentation you linked, you'll see that they're specifically using `Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();` to provide data to the flow where:

- *key* of map = name of the input variable in the flow
- *value* of key = data set in the input variable

```java
{
  Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
  inputs.put('AccountID', myAccount);
  inputs.put('OpportunityID', myOppty);
  
  Flow.Interview.Calculate_discounts myFlow = 
    new Flow.Interview.Calculate_discounts(inputs);
  myFlow.start();
}
```

As such, you'll want to pass your list of data as the value in a map that has a key that matches your collection variable name in Flow

```java
trigger InboundReferralTrigger on Inquiry__c (after insert) {

    List<Inquiry__c> inputInboundReferrals = trigger.new;
    //Create map of input variables/values for flow
    Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
    params.put('YourCollectionVariableName', inputInboundReferrals);
    
    Flow.Interview.Inbound_Referral_Apex_Triggered_Flow myFlow = new Flow.Interview.Inbound_Referral_Apex_Triggered_Flow(params);
    myFlow.start();         
}
```

If you're going through the trouble of using apex trippers to call flows - you may want to *consider* doing it all in apex. Especially, if you're iterating a lot in that flow - be aware of other [limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314438&type=1) you could run into regarding number of iterations exceeded (limit of 2000 executed elements at run time). At the very least, you may want to consider filtering your records before calling the flow if possible.

Comment: Thanks Kris. This helps a lot. Just to clarify, 'YourCollectionVariableName' should be the same as the Name of the variable in the flow that is receiving the data, right?

I may also move the Flow logic into an async path to help prevent the errors on import. Thanks for your notes about the other flow limitations to consider.

Comment: Correct - the api name.

Comment: and remember that map key match to flow input variableName is _case sensitive_